# Give an example of spaces such that the induced map on the fundamental groups $f_* : \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is injective, but not surjective

Tags: algebraic-topology

> Give an example of pointed spaces $(X, x_0)$ and $(Y, y_0)$ and a map $f : (X, x_0) \to (Y, y_0)$ such that the induced map on the fundamental groups $f_* : \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is injective, but not surjective. Give also an example where $f_* : \pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is an isomorphism, but $X$ and $Y$ are not homeomorphic.

I'm thinking for the first part that $X = S^1$ and $Y = S^1 \times S^1$ work with $i : X \hookrightarrow Y$ since now $i_*:\pi_1(X, x_0) \to \pi_1(Y, y_0)$ is a map $$\mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}\times \mathbb{Z}$$ I know that there can be a surjection like this, but I can't tell if the induced map $i_*$ is a surjection in this case.

For the second problem any $i: X \to Y$ will work whenever $X$ is a deformation retract of $Y$ and not homeomorphic to it, since then the induced map $i_\ast$ is an isomorphism so for example the cylinder and $S^1$.

Comment: This is correct. (I'm assuming that in the first example, the $S^1$ wraps around one of the two factors in the product $S^1\times S^1$.) Do you have any specific questions?

Comment: I mean I don't know whether this induced map $i_\ast$ is a surjection or not just by merely taking $i$ to be the inclusion? @KennyWong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding your first example, presumably the map $i : S^1 \to S^1 \times S^1$ is the map $i(x) = (x, c)$, where $c$ is some constant point in $S^1$. The induced homomorphism $i_\star : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$ on the fundamental groups is then given by $i_\star(n) = (n, 0)$, which is clearly not surjective.

If you want to prove that $i_\star(n) = (n, 0)$ by some rigorous argument, you can proceed as follows. Let $p_1 : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ and $p_2 : S^1 \times S^1 \to S^1$ be the natural projections onto the first and second factors in the product. Then $(p_1)_\star: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ and $(p_2)_\star: \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ are the projection homomorphisms $(p_1)_\star(n_1, n_2) = n_1$ and $(p_2)_\star(n_1, n_2) = n_2$ respectively. This is a standard result, valid for the fundamental group of any product space. Now $p_1 \circ i : S^1 \to S^1$ is the identity map $(p_1 \circ i)(x) = x$, whereas $p_2 \circ i : S^1 \to S^1$ is the constant map $(p_2 \circ i)(x) = c$. This implies that $(p_1)_\star \circ i_\star : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is the identity homomorphism $((p_1)_\star \circ i_\star) (n) = n$, whereas $(p_2)_\star \circ i_\star : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z$ is the zero homomorphism $((p_2)_\star \circ i_\star) (n) = 0$. Since $(p_1)_\star(n_1, n_2) = n_1$ and $(p_2)_\star(n_1, n_2) = n_2$, it follows that $i_\star(n) = (n, 0)$.

Incidentally, in your post, you said that there exist surjective group homomorphisms from $\mathbb Z$ to $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. This is not true! It is true that there exist surjective *functions* from the *set* $\mathbb Z$ to the *set* $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$; after all, the two sets have the same cardinality. However, there is no surjective *homomorphism* from the *group* $\mathbb Z$ to the *group* $\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Indeed, suppose for contradiction that there exists a surjective group homomorphism $\phi : \mathbb Z \to \mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z$. Then
$$\text{rank}(\mathbb Z) = \text{rank}(\text{ker}(\phi)) + \text{rank}(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z),$$
However, $\text{rank}(\mathbb Z) = 1$ and $\text{rank}(\mathbb Z \times \mathbb Z) = 2$, so we have a contradiction, whatever the value of $\text{rank}(\text{ker}(\phi))$ is.

---

I'll also remark that the problem can be solved in a simpler way. For example, we can take $X$ to be the space consisting of a single point, while taking $Y$ to be any space with a non-trivial fundamental group - for example, a circle. If $f: X \to Y$ is the unique map from $X$ to $Y$, then $f_\star$ is certainly injective but not surjective.

---

Regarding your second example, you're absolutely spot on. For example, you can take $X$ to be a cylinder while $Y$ is a circle.